# Next primes of the form $n^n - (n-1)^{n-1} - (n-2)^{n-2} - (n-3)^{n-3} - ...- 3^3 - 2^2 - 1^1 - 0^0$

Tags: prime-numbers

With the convention $0^0=1$, let

- $Q(1) = 1^1 - 0^0=1-1=0$
- $Q(2) = 2^2 - 1^1 - 0^0=4-1-1=2$
- $Q(3) = 3^3 - 2^2 - 1^1 - 0^0=27-4-1-1=21$
- $Q(4) = 4^4 - 3^3 - 2^2 - 1^1 - 0^0=256-27-4-1-1=223$
- and so on...

I found that $Q(2)=2$, $Q(4)=223$ , and $Q(7)=773{,}473$ are prime , but after that I didn't find anymore primes up to $Q(1000)$. I found these some regular patterns:

- $Q(4n+1)$ and $Q(4n+2)$ will always be even numbers for all integers $n \ge 0$
- $3$ will always be the LEAST PRIME FACTOR of $Q(36n+3) , Q(36n+8) , Q(36n+16) , Q(36n+19) , Q(36n+24)$ and $Q(36n+35)$, for all integers $n \ge 0$

I found some semiprimes but I didn't find any primes besides the already known $Q(2), Q(4)$, and $Q(7)$. Could you find the next prime(s) of such form ?

Comment: Is this problem directly related to the use of Wolfram Language or Mathematica software?

Comment: I used this :  Isprime n^n - 1 - ($sigma$ (n-1)^(n-1)  , n = 2 to n)

Comment: Isprime is not a Mathematica function and that doesn't look like Mathematica syntax.

Comment: I passed $n= 9\ 100$ , no further primes. (+1 , since I am always interested in questions about prime numbers)

Comment: I arrived at $n=11\ 000$ without finding a further prime.

Comment: According to my calculations, in the range $11\ 000\le n\le 10^{11}$ , the expected number of primes of this form is slightly larger than $1$ , which could make it infeasible to find the next prime of this form. The naive $1/ln(n)$-approach predicts infinite many primes of this form since small factors are apparently not forced, and algebraic or similar factors seem not to exist either.